# jDialog not showing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have tried to add my jPanel to a jDialog and when I trigger the button nothing happens. Why? I have the code below:
    public class fontFormat{

```
public void fontPanel(){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    panel.getPreferredSize();
    Dimension size = new Dimension();

    size.width = 400;
    size.height = 600;

    panel.setPreferredSize(size);

    panel.add(new JLabel("label"));
    panel.add(new JButton("button"));


    JDialog fontDialog = new JDialog();

    fontDialog.add(fontDialog);
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a Listener to the `JButton`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
JDialog fontDialog = new JDialog();
fontDialog.add(fontDialog);
```

You appear to be trying to add your JDialog to itself, which should cause your code to not function. While this code may compile, running this method *should* cause the JVM to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` on the `fontDialog.add(fontDialog);` line.

Please note that you show a JDialog similar to how you show a JFrame:

- When you call your JDialog constructor, you will want to pass in the parent window into it, especially if your desire is to display a modal dialog.
- You will also want to pass into the constructor the correct ModalityType enum.
- You give your JDialog content, often a JPanel with your components on it.
- You pack it
- then you call `setVisible(true)` on it, and it should display

---

For example,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogEg {
   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      MainPanelGen mainPanelGen = new MainPanelGen();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DialogEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanelGen.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }

}

class MainPanelGen {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton btn = new JButton(new BtnActn());
   private JDialog dialog;
   private DialogPanel dialogPanel = new DialogPanel();

   public MainPanelGen() {
      mainPanel.add(field);
      mainPanel.add(btn);

      field.setEditable(false);
      field.setFocusable(false);
   }

   public JPanel getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class BtnActn extends AbstractAction {
      BtnActn() {
         super("Button");
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         if (dialog == null) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
            if (win != null) {
               dialog = new JDialog(win, "My Dialog",
                     Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
               dialog.getContentPane().add(dialogPanel);
               dialog.pack();
               dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
         }
         dialog.setVisible(true); // here the modal dialog takes over
         System.out.println   (dialogPanel.getFieldText());
         field.setText(dialogPanel.getFieldText());
      }
   }
}

class DialogPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton exitBtn = new JButton(new ExitBtnAxn("Exit"));

   public DialogPanel() {
      add(field);
      add(exitBtn);
   }

   public String getFieldText() {
      return field.getText();
   }

   private class ExitBtnAxn extends AbstractAction {

      public ExitBtnAxn(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(DialogPanel.this);
         if (win != null) {
            win.dispose();
         }

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That was the problem and I thank you for all the explanations you give me!!!